# Error when run mongosh command from Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm setting up MongoDB at local use official image from MongoDB and activate replica set, but I met error when run mongosh command via entrypoint (It's still work if I ssh to container and run script).

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mongo:6

COPY /certs /certs
COPY /scripts /scripts

EXPOSE 27017

CMD ["bash", "/scripts/setup.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "/scripts/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

**/scripts/entrypoint.sh**

```bash
echo "=== Start MongoDB replica set setup ==="

echo "** Setup replica set **"
mongosh --eval "rs.initiate({_id: 'dbrs', members: [{_id: 0, host: 'localhost:27017'}]})"

echo "=== Complete MongoDB replica set setup ==="
```

And error thrown when execute this bash file via entrypoint: `MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

Have any solution to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Docker container runs a single application.

The [`mongo` container runs `CMD ["mongod"]`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/195444dd549a1fbdcf08d7938a42784301ae8695/7.0-rc/Dockerfile) to start the Mongodb process, which you're overwriting with your bash script.

Luckily, you don't need to do that.

Like many other Docker images, the `mongo` container has a directory where you can place startup scripts. The original `docker-entrypoint.sh` script (not your `entrypoint.sh`) will read `*.js` and `*.sh` files in the directory `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. To quote the README:

> ### Initializing a fresh instance
>
> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files with extensions `.sh` and `.js` that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. `.js` files will be executed by `mongosh` (`mongo` on versions below 6) using the database specified by the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` variable, if it is present, or `test` otherwise. You may also switch databases within the `.js` script.

So remove your `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions and replace `COPY /scripts /scripts` with `COPY ./scripts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

The original `docker-entrypoint.d` will start the Mongodb process and then execute the `*.sh` files (or Javascript files).